# f = Ω(log n) and g = O(n) is g(n) = O(f (n))

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science

Given two functions f = Ω(log n) and g = O(n), consider the following statements. For
each statement, write whether it is true or false. For each false statement, write two
functions f and g that show a counter-example.

```
 1) g(n) = O(f (n))
 2) f (n) = O(g(n))
 3) f (n) = Ω(log (g(n)))
 4) f (n) = Θ(log (g(n)))
 5) f (n) + g(n) = Ω(log n)
```

I know that Big O means no better than (function), and Big Omega means no worse than (function). But I don't know if that makes the above statement true or false.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a mathematics question and not a programming question. You may be able to ask a similar question on [math.se] or [cs.se], but be sure to check with their question guidelines before posting.

Comment: I think you got your definitions reversed. The [formal definitions can be found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann–Landau_notations).

Answer (score 2):

1. False. A counterexample is `g(n) = n \in O(n)` and `f(n) = log(n) \in Omega(log(n))`. Both assumptions are correct, but `g(n)`is not in  `O(f(n))`.
2. False. A counterexample is `g(n) = log(n) \in O(n)` and `f(n) = n \in Omega(log(n))`, but `f(n)` is not in `O(g(n))`.
3. True. As `f(n) \in Omega(log(n))`, it means `lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/log(n) > 0`. As `g(n) \in O(n)`, we can straightforwardly conclude that `lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/log(g(n)) > 0`. Hence `f(n) \in Omega(log(g(n))`.
4. False. A counterexample is `f(n) = n \in Omega(n)` and `g(n) = log(n) \in O(n)`, but `f(n)` is not in `theta(g(n)) = theta(log(n))`.
5. True. As `f(n) \in Omega(log(n))`, it means `lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/log(n) > 0`. Hence `A = lim_{n\to\infty} (f(n) + g(n))/log(g(n)) = f(n)/log(n) + g(n)/log(n)`. Hence, as `g(n) > 0`,  `A > 0`, and it means `f(n) + g(n) \in Omega(log(n))`.

Comment: thank you sir  but how can I solve it

Comment: @AhmedAli anytime. What do you mean by "solve it"? These are some true/false questions and I proved them by definition of the corresponding notations or disprove them by a counterexample.

Comment: i tried some thing like this but i dont know if this correct f(n)= Ω(log n) so f(n) > constant1 * log n                                     and g(n) = O(n) so g(n) < c2*n                                                                                          g(n)=O(f(n)   so g(n) < c3*f(n)  so                                                                                         g(n) <c1logn<c2*n<c3*f(n)   is that correct

Comment: @AhmedAli As I disproved, this statement is not correct. There is a counterexample. So, unfortunately, your proof seems not to be correct for statement 1.

Comment: ok i will try to understand this but realy thank you ver much